# Change color of data series in excel xyscatter chart

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I'm trying to change the color of the data points in an excel chart but everything im trying unsuccessful.

This is one method I tried, yet the points still appear blue:

```
With Chrt
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

                .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Top Platen"""
                .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yaxis
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xaxis

                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
                 With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
```

Here's another method I tried and still the data points appear blue:

```
With Chrt
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

                .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Top Platen"""
                .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yaxis
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xaxis
                .SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
```

This is only one segment of my code, I can supply additional areas if necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace the last `With` select block in the first example with this one line `.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)` It worked on a simple example I created.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I am still curious as to why what I was using was not acceptable. If you know, I'd love to hear it, but if not then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the nested `With` blocks getting confused.  Here is one way to solve it and still use nested `With` block:

```
With Chrt
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter

    Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        .Name = "=""Top Platen"""
        .Values = yaxis
        .XValues = xaxis
        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End With
```

---

Here is [Microsoft's documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) that talks about fully qualified nested `With` blocks.